# archive querying error (Mod_mam)

Tags: erlang, xmpp, ejabberd

This is the error i am getting from mod_mam, i need help to understand this

**Error Log :**

```
[error] <0.27129.40> CRASH REPORT Process <0.27129.40> with 0 neighbours exited with reason: {process_limit,{max_queue,5590}} in p1_fsm:terminate/8 line 755
2015-12-07 07:25:47.714 [error] <0.336.0> Supervisor ejabberd_c2s_sup had child undefined started with {ejabberd_c2s,start_link,undefined} at <0.27129.40> exit with reason {process_limit,{max_queue,5590}} in context child_terminated
2015-12-07 07:25:53.209 [error] <0.479.0>@gen_iq_handler:process_iq:128 {badarg,[{erlang,binary_to_atom,[null,utf8],[]},{jlib,binary_to_atom,1,[{file,"src/jlib.erl"},{line,934}]},{mod_mam,'-select/8-fun-2-',3,[{file,"src/mod_mam.erl"},{line,675}]},{lists,map,2,[{file,"lists.erl"},{line,1237}]},{mod_mam,select,8,[{file,"src/mod_mam.erl"},{line,669}]},{mod_mam,select_and_send,10,[{file,"src/mod_mam.erl"},{line,569}]},{gen_iq_handler,process_iq,6,[{file,"src/gen_iq_handler.erl"},{line,127}]},{gen_iq_handler,handle_info,2,[{file,"src/gen_iq_handler.erl"},{line,171}]}]}
```

This is related with querying archive due to lack of my knowledge of erlang i am not able to understand.please help me to understand this .

Comment: not so described question. Can you update with your script and ejabberd configuration of what you have done so that you can get some help

Comment: i am using ejabberd 15.11 recently updated    mod_mam:
    default: always
    db_type: odbc
...

Comment: That's good. Can you please update your script of what you exactly doing? And also your ejabberd configuration of mod_mam?

Comment: i have no  external script for doing it , i just followed  this link to query http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0313.html#filter-time

Answer (score 0):

Reason for the first error is that your service is overloaded:

```
{process_limit,{max_queue,5590}
```

Note that ejabberd process_limit error message is about a per process limit of the number of message in the queue. This is to avoid having a slow process or message receiver take all server resources.
It has nothing to do with Erlang number of allowed process per node.

Regarding your second error in logs, I guess this is because you have upgrade your instance from older version and have old messages in archive. We improved the code of ejabberd to support the old stored messages.
This is already committed in ejabberd head and fix will be published in ejabberd 15.12 release.

Comment: I found that process limit is around 32767 for a erlang node.do i need to increase the queue size to rectify this trouble ?

Comment: I do not understand your question as size of queue is unrelated to process limit. There is no reason for the queue to be of that size. You should understand first why your message are queueing. Probably your system is wrongly configured for the size of the platform you are trying to deploy. This is not a MAM question but more a general design question on your overall messaging solution.

Comment: please see the  log wherein it is giving badarg  [error] <0.479.0>@gen_iq_handler:process_iq:128 {badarg,[{erlang,binary_to_atom,[null,utf8],[]},{jlib,binary_to_atom,1,[{file,"src/jlib.erl"},{line,934}]},{mod_mam,'-select/8-fun-2-',3,[{file,"src/mod_mam.erl"},{line,675}]},{lists,map,2,[{file,"lists.erl"},{line,1237}]},{mod_mam,select,8,[{file,"src/mod_mam.erl"},{line,669}]},{mod_mam,select_and_send,10,[{file,"src/mod_mam.erl"},{line,569}]},{gen_iq_handler,process_iq,6,[{file,"src/gen_iq_handler.erl"},{line,127}]},{gen_iq_handler,handle_info,2,[{file,"src/gen_iq_handler.erl"},{line,171}]}]}

Comment: Yes, I have seen it. Your original log entry shows that the process exited on its own because the number of message in queue for that process was reached.

Comment: Thanks Mickael , but i think that badarg error in mod_mam is not related to queue size or causing the crash.

Comment: Maybe your database schema is not the latest one ? Which database are you using ? Did you upgrade from a previous version ?

Comment: I updated my comment. My guess is that you have messages archived from an older ejabberd version. We commited changes to ejabberd to support those older archived messages better.